# LINQ Method Syntax with INNER and OUTER Join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-method-syntax

I have 3 classes and trying to use `LINQ methods` to perform an `INNER JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN`. I'm able to perform each separately, but no luck together since I can't even figure out the syntax.

Ultimately, the SQL I'd write would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Group] AS [g]
INNER JOIN [Section] AS [s] ON [s].[GroupId] = [g].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Course] AS [c] ON [c].[SectionId] = [s].[Id]
```

**Classes**

```
public class Group {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Samples**

I want the result to be of type `Group`. I successfully performed the `LEFT JOIN` between `Section` and `Course`, but then I have an object of type `IQueryable<`a>`, which is not what I want, since`Group`.

```cs
var result = db.Section
               .GroupJoin(db.Course, 
                    s => s.Id,
                    c => c.SectionId,
                    (s, c) => new { s, c = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
               .SelectMany(s => s.c.Select(c => new { s = s.s, c }));
```

I also tried this, but returns `NULL` because this performs an `INNER JOIN` on all tables, and the user has not entered any `Courses`.

```cs
var result = db.Groups
               .Where(g => g.IsActive)
               .Include(g => g.Sections)
               .Include(g => g.Sections.Select(s => s.Courses))
               .Where(g => g.Sections.Any(s => s.IsActive && s.Courses.Any(c => c.UserId == _userId && c.IsActive)))
               .ToList();
```

**Question**

How can I perform an `INNER` and a `LEFT JOIN` with the least number of calls to the database and get a result of type `Group`?

**Desired Result**

I would like to have 1 object of type `Group`, but only as long as a `Group` has a `Section`. I also want to return the `Courses` the user has for the specific `Section` or return `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you ask for is impossible without returning a new (anonymous) object instead of `Group` (as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410305/1300910)). EF will not allow you to get a filtered `Course` collection inside a `Section` because of the way relations and entity caching works, which means you can't use navigational properties for this task.

First of all, you want to have control over which related entities are loaded, so I suggest to enable lazy loading by marking the `Sections` and `Courses` collection properties as `virtual` in your entities (unless you've enabled lazy loading for all entities in your application) as we don't want EF to load related `Sections` and `Courses` as it would load all courses for each user anyway.

```
public class Group {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class Section {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

In method syntax, the query would probably look something like this:

```
var results = db.Group
    .Where(g => g.IsActive)
    .GroupJoin(
        db.Section.Where(s => s.IsActive),
        g => g.Id,
        s => s.GroupId,
        (g, s) => new
        {
            Group = g,
            UserSections = s
                .GroupJoin(
                    db.Course.Where(c => c.IsActive && c.UserId == _userId).DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    ss => ss.Id,
                    cc => cc.SectionId,
                    (ss, cc) => new
                    {
                        Section = ss,
                        UserCourses = cc
                    }
                )
        })
    .ToList();
```

And you would consume the result as:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var group = result.Group;

    foreach (var userSection in result.UserSections)
    {
        var section = userSection.Section;

        var userCourses = userSection.UserCourses;

    }
}
```

Now, if you don't need additional filtering of the group results on database level, you can as well go for the INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN approach by using this LINQ query and do the grouping in-memory:

```
var results = db.Group
    .Where(g => g.IsActive)
    .Join(
        db.Section.Where(s => s.IsActive),
        g => g.Id,
        s => s.GroupId,
        (g, s) => new
        {
            Group = g,
            UserSection = new
            {
                Section = s,
                UserCourses = db.Course.Where(c => c.IsActive && c.UserId == _userId && c.SectionId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
            }
        })
    .ToList() // Data gets fetched from database at this point
    .GroupBy(x => x.Group) // In-memory grouping
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Group = x.Key,
        UserSections = x.Select(us => new
        {
            Section = us.UserSection,
            UserCourses = us.UserSection.UserCourses
        })
    });
```

Remember, whenever you're trying to access `group.Sections` or `section.Courses`, you will trigger the lazy loading which will fetch all child section or courses, regardless of `_userId`.

Comment: Thank! Looks like a promising answer. I'll work on it and let you know the results. I Actually lazy load (mark `virtual` on all my properties), which is why my initial sample code uses `.Include(...)` to fetch them right away. Does that affect your answer?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you had lazy loading enabled. Also, if you only need read access, use `db.Group.AsNoTracking()` instead of `db.Group`.

Comment: o.0 Thanks! Didn't know about `.AsNoTracking()`. I assume this saves some server resources? Or what else is it good for?

Comment: It improves query speed greatly as it tells EF not to track the returned entities for changes.

Comment: Thanks. I have not yet tested it. I Will test it soon and let you know the results.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` to perform an outer left join

```
from g in db.group
join s in db.section on g.Id equals s.GroupId 
join c in db.course on c.SectionId equals s.Id into courseGroup
from cg in courseGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { g, s, c };
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `LINQ Methods` instead of `LINQ Query`?

Comment: This is true, but I like to learn different methods and wanted a `LINQ Methods` version. =) I guess I should have stated I can already do it with `LINQ Query` =)

Comment: As I understand, `c` can't be used in `select` and `cg` should be used: `select new { g, s, cg };`

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL's type is not [Group] (Type group would be: select [Group].* from ...), anyway if you want it like that, then in its simple form it would be:

```
var result = db.Groups.Where( g => g.Sections.Any() );
```

However, if you really wanted to convert your SQL, then:

```
var result = from g in db.Groups
             from s in g.Sections
             from c in s.Courses.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {...};
```

Even this would do:

```
var result = from g in db.Groups
             select new {...};
```

Hint: In a well designed database with relations, you very rarely need to use join keyword. Instead use navigational properties.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. This is very well designed with proper relations IMO, however the reason I need this is because I want all the active `Sections`, but a student may not have `Courses` in all `Sections`. Maybe my knowledge of LINQ is not =) and I might be doing something wrong. Going to test something.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs, OK. I suggest you to download and use the wonderful LinqPad (linqPad.net) tool. When you add your connection to it, it would automatically deduct the model and help you in writing the complex Linq.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it. Let me ask you a side-question before I go further: If I write something like `var result = db.Groups.Include(g => g.Sections)` would it return `Groups` that do not have `Sections` assigned yet or would `Sections` be `NULL`?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs, yes it would. Linqpad is the fastest way to test the idea (and get SQL, lambda calls as well:) rereading your question not sure if I understood correctly, best test it to see yourself.

Comment: Ah!, then I have a totally different question to ask. I thought `.Include(...)` was like a `INNER JOIN`, which then would not return any `Groups` without a `Section`. doh! I'll do some tests and post a new question.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs, I edited my answer really. I am not sure if I understood it right. Please test it to see what it returns. You get the groups, with or without sections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176287/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-rolyrolls).

Comment: Ok, so `Include(...)` **does** work like an `INNER JOIN`, which is why I suspected I needed to do something differently. But I wanted a `LINQ Method` version and not a `LINQ Query` version.